# format string python with varying number of placeholders

Tags: python, string

```py
    def SumFunc(E,n):
        write_path = open('somepath.text','a')
        some function here evaluates the following...
        c1 = 
        c2 = 
        c4 = 
        c4 =  
        write_path.write('{} {} {} {} {}\n'.format(E,c1,c2,c3,c4))
```

I have a function with depends on **'E'** and **'n'**, where **'n'** is the number of place holders in the end, which in this case is 5. My **'n'** varies from 4 to 100 for different examples.

My question is how can I format the writing on file so that it works for all **'n'**. Like in *n=4* it writes with *4* place holders and when *n=50* it creates *50* placeholders and write *50* values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your values ( Cs ) stored in a list let's call it `c_list`

Then generate your string this way:

```
string = ' '.join([str(x) for x in c_list]) + '\n'
write_path.write(string)
```

Comment: Cs are actually entries of a matrix(like nx1 matrix).

Comment: It kinda worked. Only problem is I do not need cs as string they are real numbers. My program gives me an error even after removing str in front of x

Comment: what is the point of removing `str` ? your goal is to write to a file anyway.

`str` here is needed to use the `join`

Comment: glad I helped :)

Comment: @Kumarm 
`string = str(E)+' '+' '.join([str(x) for x in c_list]) + '\n'`

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out. Sorry for two many questions. I am a Math student.